How can I search for a specific page in Safari tab groups?
Apple introduced tab groups some time ago and now I have many of them.
The problem is I can't remember sometimes which group I put a particular page into.
I looked everywhere for how to search the tab groups for a specific page but to no avail. All I get is basic usage information, and how to look at all open tabs within a group using the "Show Tab Overview" button.
Is there a way to search all the open tabs at once for a page I already have open? As an example, I have theverge.com open in my News tab group. But what if I can't remember where I put that open tab?
How can I find it within Safari?

As long as you know the name of the tab (i.e. "The Verge"), you can open a new Tab within any Tab Group and search for it.  In the example below, I searched for the word "verge" and Safari was able to find it.
On selecting the result in Switch to Tab, Safari will bring the window with the relevant Tab Group into focus at that tab, or if the Tab Group is not currently open in a separate window, it will switch the current window to that Tab Group at the required tab.

Below is another example, but this time using the word "memory" to find the tab with "Memory Toys"


Thanks I have never seen the “Switch to Tab” choice.  I just thought there should be a find window for all open tabs.

Is it possible to externally script this?

Open a new tab in any tab group, then type some terms from the tab title or URL into the search bar.
Matching tabs from any tab group will be shown at the top of the ‘Bookmarks, History and Tabs’ section, including the name of the tab group that the tab is in. Choosing this option closes the new tab and switches to the tab group for the tab, focusing the existing tab for the result.

